# IE fails Jquery.html with Permission Denied

Tags: c#, jquery, innerhtml

I have an ajax call that works fine in Firefox, but I am getting a permission denied error in the jquery.min.js file. I have no idea what is wrong, or how to fix it. Here is my post:

(everything declared before posting)

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "../ajaxURLs/SearchRequests.aspx?requestID=" + requestID + "&state=" + state + "&status=" + status + "&queue=" + queue + "&oem=" + oem +
        "&rayMatNumber=" + rayMatNumber + "&mfgPartNumber=" + mfgPartNumber + "&program=" + program + "&po=" + po + "&pr=" + pr +
        "&businessUnit=" + businessUnit + "&site=" + site + "&buyer=" + buyer + "&requisitioner=" + requisitioner + "&ce=" + ce + "&rea=" + rea + "&pqe=" + pqe +
        "&startDate=" + startDate + "&endDate=" + endDate,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#searchResults").html(data);
            sorttable.makeSortable(document.getElementById("SearchResults"));
            $("#MainContent_excelDiv").show();
        }
    });
```

Any ideas? If I take map directly to my SearchRequests.aspx and pass it parameters, then it works fine in both Firefox and IE, it's only when it is done through ajax.

Yes, I used f12. The error is "Permission Denied" jquery.min.js, line 9 character 2805. I am using jquery version 1.7.2.

If I remove setting the searchResults div equal to data, and add an alert to show the data, it completes that action and has the correct information in the alert. Fiddler shows the correct html being generated, Firefox works fine, it's just IE. Other ajax posts work fine in IE as well.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? IE has debugger (F12) with min-script-formatter, so it should not be too hard to reason about an error. For question itself at least provide exact error, and location where it happens.

Comment: First of all if you are going to use POST you should not pass your data in the query string; that is what the `data` option is for.  Second of all could you post the error message verbatim?

Comment: @marteljn, post it as answer - I bet "POST" is exactly what is failing for OP.

Comment: @shawleigh17, please check if you agree with my edit of your question (title change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching your `type` from `POST` to `GET`.  You are doing a search so that is appropriate anyway.  That would explain why it works in the scenario described and not with your AJAX request.

`POST` should only be used when you are modifying data on the server-side whereas `GET` is for read-only data retrieval.

**Edit**

Replace `$("#searchResults").html(data);` with `document.getElementById("searchResults").innerHTML = data;` Something weird is happening in that JQuery statement, see if not using JQuery in that instance will work. If it shows up in an alert it should work in that context as well.

Comment: Are all of your resources coming from the same domain (even sub-domain), protocol (http/https) and port?  This sounds like it potentially could be a cross-domain/same-origin policy issue.

Comment: +1 as it was god guess based on original question. @shawleigh17, so your actual error is `$("#searchResults").html(data);` failing due to value of `data` (and has nothing to do with ajax querying), correct?

Comment: Another question is are you by chance dealing with frames or iframes?  I'm trying to come up with reasons you may receive a permission denied error.

Comment: I have no idea. It works fine in firefox, and shows everything correctly in fiddler and if I access the ajax page directly. The value the pops up in the alert is correct, as well. Everything is coming from the same domain/protocol/port, as far as I know. It is all on the same server. What are things that may be wrong with the data that causes it to forward to a blank page?

Comment: No, I'm not dealing with IFrames... I typically code in firefox because it is much easier to debug, since IE gives me hardly any information, so I don't really know for sure if this has ever worked or not.

Comment: Try adding `"dataType" : "html"` or whatever type you are expecting your return to be tour ajax options.

Comment: Replace `$("#searchResults").html(data);` with `document.getElementById("searchResults").innerHTML` = data;  Something weird is happening in that JQuery statement, see if not using JQuery in that instance will work.  If it shows up in an alert it should work in that context as well.

Comment: You're a baller. Thank you! Yeah, jquery was being weird. Thank you so much!